React Native iOS Build Fails, RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider.h File Not Found
I'm working on a React Native project using Expo and I'm encountering an issue when trying to build the iOS version of my app. The build fails with this error:

❌  error: /Users/jonastirona/Documents/NutrisyncFrontend/node_modules/react-native/React/Fabric/RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider.h: No such file or directory (in target 'React-RCTFabric' from project 'Pods')

My react native version is 0.76.5, expo version is 52.0.23, and I'm on macOS. The command I run when I get the error is:

npx expo run:ios --device.

To fix the error, I've tried cleaning the cache:
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf ios/Pods
rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock
npm install
cd ios
pod install
cd ..

Updating my podfile, cleaning my build folder, and rebuilding the project, but i still get the same error.
What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
